getting S3 access denied while creating a delta table using trino, aws glue on S3
I have setup Trino with delta_lake catalog as per following configuration
connector.name=delta_lake
hive.metastore=glue
hive.metastore.glue.region=eu-west-3
hive.metastore.glue.aws-access-key=<maskedaccesskey>
hive.metastore.glue.aws-secret-key=<maskedsecretkey>
hive.metastore.glue.catalogid=<maskedcatalogid>

I am running following create table query.
trino>USE delta_lake."mygluedatabasename";
USE

trino:mygluedatabasename> CREATE TABLE orders (
                  ->   order_id bigint,
                  ->   order_status varchar,
                  ->   totalprice double,
                  ->   order_date date
                  -> )
                  -> WITH (location = 's3a://mys3bucket/deltalake/orders')
                  ->
                  -> ;
Query 20240410_100938_00015_mpd3c failed: Access Denied (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied; Request ID: XKAVYKRE51Z3KG6A; S3 Extended Request ID: yWIVi5SiVjes64QGN1rHzYWV+Q/kSCMpLzTzMdtBtnic+MROgcFWa/6TsRYm7bQI57poBJ3kKCc3bDPIjk4lXB==; Proxy: null)

I checked all the read and write permissions, I am to perform all the required operations on s3 bucket using access/secret key like list-object-versions, get-bucket-location, get-object, delete-object, put-object. Still I am getting permission denied error.

I missed following properties
hive.s3.aws-access-key
hive.s3.aws-secret-key

After adding these, i was able to create delta table.
